# Finding conditions for certain intersections to be nonempty

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

During my research in algorithms I came up with the following problem which I didn't manage to solve after weeks of efforts.

Let ${\cal A}={A_1,\dots\,A_n}$ be a set of $n$ finite sets, similarly ${\cal B}={B_1,\dots\,B_m}$ a set of $m$ finite sets. Find a quantifier-free condition on $\cal A,\cal B$ that is equivalent to the following statement: there exists no set $X$ that shares at least one element with each of the sets in $\cal A$, and does not share at least one element with each of the sets in $\cal B$.

In other words, no $X$ exists s.t. $X\cap A_i\neq\emptyset$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ and $X^C\cap B_i\neq\emptyset$ for all $j=1,\dots,m$.

The problem is stated with a quantifier: "exists $X$". But empirically I found out that it's probably possible to express this condition solely in terms of union/intersection/complement/cardinality over the elements of $\cal A,\cal B$.

Alternatively, an algorithm to determine whether the statement holds given $\cal A,B$ will be very helpful.

Example: for $n=m=1$ the solution is easy. $\neg\exists X.A_1\cap X\neq\emptyset\wedge B_1\cap X^C\neq\emptyset$ iff $A_1=B_1\wedge|A_1|=1$.

Comment: from my investigations, the finiteness condition does not seem relevant.

Comment: It follows from your definition that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ and $\bigcup \mathcal{B}$ are both finite, and then so is the union of them. Then, if such $X$  exists, there must be one that is a subset of this union, and there a finite number of those, so you could try them all.

Comment: This also implies that the quantifier is bounded, and therefore logically equivalent to a formula without quantifiers.

Comment: The quantifier will be bounded only in case that we know the sizes beforehand, but I'm interested in a formula that works for any A,B.

Comment: Interesting problem, it seems difficult to find an efficient algorithm

Comment: @Troy McClure what is $X^C$? Or what is the universe set $U$ under consideration?

Comment: U can basically be anything, and I guess the problem is hardest when constraining |U|=n. So for simplicity can assume that U is the natural numbers and the A's and B's are finite sets.